# Created a drupal theme, but now I can't login?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes

I'm new to drupal so please explain like I'm 5 years old.

I created a new theme for my drupal 7 setup.  It consists of the `info` file and a `page.tpl.php`

Inside page.tlp.php I have literally placed `hello, this is my theme`. Nothing else.

I enabled the theme and disabled all the others, I made my theme the default.

So as expected the homepage returns my text.  However, I had assumed that going to `http://mysite.com/?q=user` would show me some sort of default login.  Apparently not?  There is no login form and it only shows `hello, this is my theme`

I think my assumption that the login form would always be there was incorrect.  Do I have to code this into my theme?

What would be a simple way to do this, if at all?

Thank you for your patience with my newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy things firstly from an existing theme, and modify only some parts of the template pages and see what happens. In page.tpl.php is rendered the whole page like header, footer, sidebar first where the login form is usually, sidebar second, etc.. that's why login form does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change setting.php to previous if you have made any changes in it for this theme (and archive your present setting.php).
2. Delete your fold with this theme from fold THEMES.
3. http://mysite.com/?q=user (http://mysite.com/user)
4. Login.
5. Change theme to correct one.